# Setting up a Python environment to point to a modules directory on a Mac

Tags: python, pythonpath, zshrc

I'm trying to set up a local development environment for Python. We use BitBucket for source control of Python modules we've developed for our company. On my machine I have this folder/directory set up:

```
~/xxxxxxx/Development/Git/xxxxxx/modules/
```

This serves as my local repo for the BitBucket repo.

In my .zshrc file I pointed $PYTHONPATH to this directory:

```
export PYTHONPATH="~/Desktop/xxxxxx/Development/Git/xxxxxxx/modules/"
```

In Terminal, when I put in this command: echo $PYTHONPATH I get what I expect:

```
 xxxxxxxxxxx@Steves-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $PYTHONPATH
~/Desktop/xxxxxx/Development/Git/xxxxxx/modules/
```

I then wrote this short script:

```
import os
import datetime
import json
from jira import JIRA
from jira.client import ResultList
from jira.resources import Issue
import importlib

# import modules from relative paths
colors = importlib.import_module('modules.colors')
mondayManager = importlib.import_module('modules.mondayManager')
jiraManager = importlib.import_module('modules.jiraManager')
appManager = importlib.import_module('modules.appManager')

###############################
# APP STARTS HERE             #
###############################

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("What's up dude?")
```

I get an error on the first import:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

I am obviously doing something wrong or misunderstanding how this is suppose to function, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you perhaps running your script with 'python' instead of 'python3' with multiple python installations on your machine?

Comment: I do have multiple installs but the script is run from an alias in the zsh file: 

alias runMonGetPoints='python3 ~/Desktop/xxxxxxxx/Development/Python/xxxxxxx/monGetPoints.py'

Note this is a different path than where the modules are - modules are Dev/Git/ but my understanding was that was the point of setting the $PYTHONPATH, that directory would be available regardless of where the script was run from.